# Can someone please show me how to install veracrypt directly from the veracrypt website?

Tags: veracrypt

So I installed veracrypt from a PPA repository but someone said on Reddit that is dangerous and I should only install it from the veracrypt website, but I'm a newb and I don't know how?

So I actually installed veracrypt from this website's instructions here https://linuxhint.com/install-use-veracrypt-ubuntu-22-04/ and I even encrypted an external hard drive. But now I got someone on reddit saying it's much safer to download from the veracrypt website, ok, but I'm a total novice and I need someone to hold my hand and show me how. https://veracrypt.fr/en/Downloads.html

Or can I just continue to use the veracrypt that I got from a repository?

Comment: It should make no difference when the versions are the same. Of course, PPAs are 3rd party repositories and it'0s up to you, the user, to do due diligence in assuring its reliability. At the Veracrypt website you'll find both a .deb file, installable like any other software (recommend for Debian(Ubuntu and newbies) and a generic Linux installation script that does the same and you just have to run it and follow instructions.

Comment: @ChanganAuto  I only recently switched over to linux, I was a lifelong Windows user, so what is a .deb file? Please understand I was a lifelong Windows user. Will you please give me  step-by-step instructions on how to install it from the website directly? Thank you.

Comment: If your already installed from the PPA you're fine. It's being managed by the Xubuntu community according to the link you posted. It has the advantage of receiving updates alongside the system updates whereas installing from the installer at the website won't (you'd need to visit the website regularly, keep track of new versions, and repeat the process for any new version). What you've been reading is pure FUD.

Comment: So you're saying my veracrypt that I installed from the PPA repository will automatically update itself when the developers release a new veracrypt? Also if you google "how to install veracrypt on ubuntu" the very first article that pops up is that linuxhint website that shows you the way to install veracrypt using the PPA repository. I mean, yeah I've already installed veracrypt using the PPA repository and I've already encrypted an external HDD using it, so I think I'm just going to stick with the repository one, so I'm safe then?

Comment: Yes, that's it in a nutshell.

Comment: Yeah I had already installed veracrypt using the PPA repository and encrypted an external HDD and then someone on reddit said "no that's not safe", which got me scared and confused. But the thing is many online tutorials are recommending that PPA repository for installing veracrypt, so if it wasn't safe then why are so many websites recommending it?